# Illegal string offset - searching by string with ACF (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a problem with using ACF Gallery with search engine (WOOF on Wordpress, but I think problem appear with any search engine).

I am using ACF gallery to display color of products on list, next to product. When I am searching them by search engine, by attributes - colors are displayed:
[colors displayed](http://wykladziny.pl/sklep/?swoof=1&pa_typ_obiektu=biura)

In my search engine I have also searching by text, so after searching by text colors are'nt displaying: [problem](http://wykladziny.pl/sklep/?swoof=1&woof_text=Optima)

I've got "Illegal string offset" so clearly I am trying reach string, as it was an array.

So am I understanding it right: if I search product by its attributes I am getting an array, but when I try to get
product by its name I am reaching only string? How to resolve this?

Code:

```
$images = get_field('colors');

if( is_array($images) ) { ?>
        <?php 
        for ($i = 0;$i < count($images) && $i < 38;$i++) { ?>


        <img src="<?php echo $images[$i]['sizes']['thumbnail']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $images[$i]['alt']?>" />         
   <?php } ?>  
<?php }
else if (!is_array($images)) {
    $image = acf_get_attachment($images);

        for ($i = 0;$i < count($image) && $i < 38;$i++) { ?>

<img src="<?php echo $image[$i][$thumb]; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image[$i]['alt']?>" />    
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink() ?>" class="btn-2" style="margin-top: 30px;margin-right: 40px;">Więcej informacji</a> 
</div>
```

EDIT:

I did var_dump on array $images.

When searching by string (by the name of product) array is not showing right data.
[image]

When I am searching by attributes (as I mentioned, I am using this plugin WOOF Product Filtering for Woocommerce, attributes of products such as material, ect. are signed to the products) everything is okay, I am getting:
[image]
Full array with every data as it should be (below are also color images).

So when I am searching by string I've got illegal string offset, array is not showing right data, images are missing.

When I am searching by attributes everything is okay.

Anyone have an idea how can I solve it? 
Help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Problem still not solved. Anybody?